# How to send random wasd keystrokes in a specific application in Python?

Tags: python

I have some code below and I believe `PyGetWindow` could be implemented into it but I'm not sure how

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

import random
import time

key_press_dict = {
    0 : 'w',
    1 : 'a',
    2 : 's',
    3 : 'd'
}

# Virtual keyboard initialization
keyboard = Controller()

while True: # Loop until time depletes
    random_key_press = key_press_dict[random.randint(0,3)]
    print(random_key_press)
    keyboard.press(random_key_press)
    time.sleep(random.uniform(.18, .5))
    keyboard.release(random_key_press)
```

If you have any idea how to implement `PyGetWindow` into the code above, please let me know.